# UV transformations in UV Editor are not updating in the 3D Viewport

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I UV unwrapped an object in my scene, then scale transformed the UV islands to make the faces proportionally similar to how they look on the object. However, I noticed none of the changes I make in the UV Editor are reflected in my 3D Viewport. As you can see in the image below, the scale of the texture in the 3D Viewport is vastly different between the faces despite the scale of the UV islands in the UV Editor. The scale is off in rendered view as well. Any idea how I would apply the changes I made to the object's UVs to the object?

I've tried applying the solutions that were on threads for similar problems by adding a Texture Coordinate and Mapping Node, and making sure I have the right UV Map set to render in the Object Data Properties, but neither of those solutions seemed to work for me.
[image: UV Editor and 3D Viewport][image: Node Structure]

Comment: Your image texture looks flat.  Your variation is coming from the normal map, which isn't using UV whatsoever-- it's using generated texture coordinates, which are totally unrelated.  Unplug your normal map to verify the problem.  If you want to control your normal map via your UV, use UV instead of generated texture coordinates for it.

Comment: Ah, I knew it had to be something dumb I did in the nodes! Switching the Texture Coordinate node's output to UV instead of Generated fixed it. Thank you very much!